# Efficient way to delete line containing certain text in vim with prompt

Tags: vim, vi

At present i can search for text

```
/text
```

and then delete line using `dd` and if i don't want to delete i can go for next match with `n`.

**But is there any more fast way to do that!**

This command below deletes all the lines containing text, but the problem is that it deletes all lines at once, sometimes that text is in some line that is exception.

```
:g/text/d
```

But i want something simple like like

```
:%s/text/some_other_text/gc
```

because this gives the option to substitute or not to.

Comment: `%s/text.*\n//gc` will do

Comment: Thanks LievenKeersmaekers, you are substituting the **text ** up to the line end **\n** using regular expression with nothing**//**. That's great as it highlights where the **text** is in line to make decision of deletion, but it isn't deleting the line from start to finish.

Comment: It's surprising that global ex command doesn't offer a `confirm' option, though

Answer (score 38):

You don't need a global command for this. The substitute command in by itself will suffice by

- adding a wildcard
- and adding an end-of-line.

**example**

```
%s/.*text.*\n//gc
```

Comment: To answer a previous comment, the pattern should be `.*text.*\n`

Comment: @LucHermitte - what comment are you talking about?

Comment: I speaking about OP's comment when you've commented his/her question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781951/efficient-way-to-delete-line-containing-certain-text-in-vim-with-prompt/46807561?noredirect=1#comment80525803_46781951

Comment: @LucHermitte - thanks, I've completely missed that. I have adjusted my answer. Do you happen to know why the `g` solution doesn't work if a match is found on consecutive lines? I assume it has to do with marking the lines where the global command is applied to, before applying the substitute.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. You mean why `:g/pattern/s/.*\n//gc` doesn't always work?

Comment: Yes. The solution romainl posted doesn't work *(for me at least)* when there are consecutive lines containing a match. It's easily tested by creating a file with only two lines containg `text`. Only one line get's deleted.

Comment: Could you please explain the regex? What does each character mean `.`, `*` and why does it work when placed in those exact locations..

Comment: @analytical_prat - the regex is `.*text.*\n`. `.*` in a regex is *match all* characters. That exact location is where the substitute command expects a search string. Look up `:help :substitute` for that.

Answer (score 19):

You can mix `:help global` and `:help substitute`:

```
:g/text/s/.*\n//c
```

This will ask for confirmation before deleting every line containing `text`:

[image]

Comment: Ah found it: try your solution with only aaaa's in the input file. It won't work.

Comment: Thanks @romainl
This will work in case of short line but in case if the line is long i have to search where the **text** is in it.
To me, searching for (`/text`) and then deleting line (`dd`) is even more convenient as i can find with highlight where the text is present.

Comment: @AmritpalNagraMe - I'd love to be proven wrong but this doesn't work when you have consecutive lines containing your search string.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers is right. The `\n` moves the cursor one line past the matched one, and thus two consecutive matches are ignored. Try this instead: `:g/pattern/-1s/\n.*//gc`

Comment: @LucHermitte - That breaks if the first line matches :S

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to found a way to use `global` and `:substitute`, and that correctly handles matches on consecutive lines, and matches on the first line, but alas, I'm not inspired.

So, I'm back to my basics: I've implemented what I think is missing: `:confirm global`.

[The result has been pushed in my library plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/commit/09262a723e70c9bcfcd54e791664a12d6f334e5a).

How it works:

1. I prepare a stateful variable that remembers the previous user choice when it matters (*always*, or *quit*, or *last*).
2. I execute `global` on the pattern, and for each match I check what the user wishes to do.

   - I either use the *don't-ask-again* states
   - or I ask using the `StatusLineNC` highlight group with `echo "\rmessage"` + `:redraw`. This is a very old trick we used to do even before Vim 6 IIRC.

The related code is the following:

```
" Function: lh#ui#ask(message) {{{3
function! lh#ui#ask(message) abort
  redraw! " clear the msg line
  echohl StatusLineNC
  echo "\r".a:message
  echohl None
  let key = nr2char(getchar())
  return key
endfunction

" Function: lh#ui#confirm_command(command) {{{3
" states:
" - ask
" - ignore
" - always
function! s:check() dict abort
  if     self.state == 'ignore'
    return
  elseif self.state == 'always'
    let shall_execute_command = 1
  elseif self.state == 'ask'
    try
      let cleanup = lh#on#exit()
            \.restore('&cursorline')
            \.restore_highlight('CursorLine')
      set cursorline
      hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=black ctermfg=white guibg=black guifg=white
      let choice = lh#ui#ask(self.message)
      if     choice == 'q'
        let self.state = 'ignore'
        let shall_execute_command = 0
        " TODO: find how not to blink
        redraw! " clear the msg line
      elseif choice == 'a'
        let self.state = 'always'
        let shall_execute_command = 1
        " TODO: find how not to blink
        redraw! " clear the msg line
      elseif choice == 'y'
        " leave state as 'ask'
        let shall_execute_command = 1
      elseif choice == 'n'
        " leave state as 'ask'
        let shall_execute_command = 0
      elseif choice == 'l'
        let shall_execute_command = 1
        let self.state = 'ignore'
      endif
    finally
      call cleanup.finalize()
    endtry
  endif

  if shall_execute_command
    execute self.command
  endif
endfunction

function! s:getSID() abort
  return eval(matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\zs\d\+\ze_getSID$'))
endfunction
let s:k_script_name      = s:getSID()

function! lh#ui#make_confirm_command(command, message) abort
  let res = lh#object#make_top_type(
        \ { 'state': 'ask'
        \ , 'command': a:command
        \ , 'message': a:message . ' (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)'
        \ })
  call lh#object#inject_methods(res, s:k_script_name, 'check')
  return res
endfunction

" Function: lh#ui#global_confirm_command(pattern, command, message [, sep='/']) {{{3
" Exemple: to remove lines that match a pattern:
" > call lh#ui#global_confirm_command(pattern, 'd', 'delete line?')
function! lh#ui#global_confirm_command(pattern, command, message, ...) abort
  let cmd = lh#ui#make_confirm_command(a:command, a:message)
  let sep = get(a:, 1, '/')
  exe 'g'.sep.a:pattern.sep.'call cmd.check()'
endfunction

" Function: lh#ui#_confirm_global(param) {{{3
function! lh#ui#_confirm_global(param) abort
  let sep = a:param[0]
  let parts = split(a:param, sep)
  if len(parts) < 2
    throw "Not enough arguments to `ConfirmGlobal`!"
  endif
  let cmd = join(parts[1:])
  call lh#ui#global_confirm_command(parts[0], cmd, cmd . ' on line?', sep)
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 ConfirmGlobal call lh#ui#_confirm_global('<args>')
```

From here you could either type:

- `:call lh#ui#global_confirm_command(pattern, 'd', 'delete line?')`
- or `:ConfirmGlobal/pattern/d` which generates a less instructive prompt

Comment: It's quite amazing all this is needed for what appears a simple, valid use case *(or to put it another way: amazing it doesn't work out of the box)*

Comment: Well, `:%s/.*text.*\n//gc` works very well and out of the box. there may be a valid solution that involve `:g` + `:s`, but as I said, I wasn't inspired to find it.

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way is to combine :glboal and :norm

```
:g/test/norm dd
```

Comment: how is this different from `:g/test/d` ?